# Typescript + JQueryUI sortstop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, typescript

I'm trying to attach a sortstop event to an element.
See: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop

```
$("#Scroller").on("sortstop", function( event, ui ) {
}
```

The typescript compiler keeps kicking up a warning that the handler only takes one parameter ..event http://api.jquery.com/on/

So if I do this, it's OK

```
$("#Scroller").on("sortstop", function( event ) {
}
```

But then I don't get the ui element.

I have the JQueryUI Type file included in the page. So I'd expect the compiler to know that function( event, ui ) is a valid handler signature.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: not recommended but you could do `var ui = arguments[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You should include the JQuery UI .d.ts file so that the TypeScript compiler knows the types of the JQueryUI elements. You can use the .d.ts from here https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jqueryui/jqueryui.d.ts.

This has a `SortableEvent` interface which defines the ui parameter

```
interface SortableEvent {
    (event: JQueryEventObject, ui: SortableUIParams): void;
}
```